# How can I catch the exception if IPV6 address is passed

Tags: java, ipv6, inetaddress

This is my below code and I want to catch the exception if any IPV6 address is passed. Any idea how it can be done in my code?

```
private static boolean validateAnIpAddress(String ipAddr) {  

     InetAddress address = null;
     boolean isIPv4;

        try {
            address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr);
            isIPv4 = address.getHostAddress().equals(ipAddr) && address instanceof Inet4Address;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            //return false;
            isIPv4 = false;
        }

        return isIPv4;

     }
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Do you want to accept only IPv4 addresses and reject everything else?

Comment: Yes, but if any IPv6 address is passed then I want to log using logger. So this line `isIPv4 = address.getHostAddress().equals(ipAddr) && address instanceof Inet4Address;` checks for only IPV4 address right?

Comment: Why on earth would someone want to reject IPv6 addresses in a new program? We are in 2012, not in 1992...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
    address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr);

    boolean isIPv6 = address instanceof Inet6Address;
    if (isIPv6)
        throw new UnknownHostException("IPv6 Address");

    isIPv4 = address.getHostAddress().equals(ipAddr) && address instanceof Inet4Address;
}
```

By checking if `address` is an `Inet6Address` type, you can throw the exception inside the `try` block and therefore triggering your `catch` block.

Comment: Ok. So that means this line `isIPv4 = address.getHostAddress().equals(ipAddr) && address instanceof Inet4Address;` is only used to check the IPv4 address right? Any other use of this line?

Comment: The first part checks if the IP address is valid at all and the second checks if it is an IPv4 address.

Comment: So by this line `isIPv4 = address.getHostAddress().equals(ipAddr) && address instanceof Inet4Address;` it checks for IPv4 address  and this line `isIPv6 = address instanceof Inet6Address` is to check for IPv6 address right?

Comment: @RaihanJamal The first part of the isIPv4 check insures that you actually have an IP Address, and not a hostname that happens to have resolved to an IPv4 address.  Without that check, you could pass in "google.com" in `ipAddr`, and it would report that it was an IPv4 address, because the name resolves to an IPv4 address, even though "google.com" itself isn't.

Comment: @RaihanJamal John is correct. And `isIPv6 = address instanceof Inet6Address` checks if `address` represents an IPv6 address.